# defined-or "//" over multiple lines

Tags: raku

Why are version 1,2 and 3 working, but version 4 fails with: `Null regex not allowed` when using `//` over multiple lines?

```
#1
say Nil         //
    try {'a'++} //
    1;

#2
say    Nil
    // try {'a'++} //
       2;

#3
say   Nil
   // 3;

#Fails with: Null regex not allowed
say        Nil
        // try {'a'++}
        // 4;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is `try` block at the end of a line.
It is same as

```
say        Nil
    // try {'a'++};
    // 4;
```

See documentation: 
[It is OK to skip the semicolon between the last statement in a block and the closing `}`.](https://docs.perl6.org/language/control#index-entry-control_flow__blocks-blocks)

You can try

```
say        Nil
    // try {'a'++}\
    // 4;
```

or

```
say        Nil
    // (try {'a'++})
    // 4;
```